# If X and Y are independent, then $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to show the following:

If X and Y are independent, then their generated sigma-algebras $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are independent.

Let $A \in \sigma(X)$ and $B\in\sigma(Y)$ be arbitrary.

W.l.o.g. i can suppose that $A=\Omega\setminus X $ and $B=\Omega \setminus Y$

**Question:** I think we can suppose this, because if there were more set-operations which connects $X$ and $B$ they would cancel out in the below argumentation.

We have:

$P(X)=P(\Omega)-P(A)$

$P(Y)=P(\Omega)-P(B)$, hence

$P(X\cap Y)=P(X)\cdot P(Y)=(P(\Omega)-P(A))\cdot(P(\Omega)-P(B))=P(\Omega)^2-P(\Omega)P(B)-P(\Omega)P(A)+P(A)P(B)=1-P(B)-P(A)+P(A)P(B)$

We also have:

$P(X\cap Y)=P((\Omega\setminus A)\cap (\Omega\setminus B))=P(\Omega\setminus(A\cup B))=P(\Omega)-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cup B)=1-P(A)-P(B)+P(A\cup B)$

From which the statement follows.

Edit: Original exercise:

[image]

Comment: Are you under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are sets?

Comment: I have no informations about X and Y. I guess the author of the task means that X and Y are measurable sets, so elements of two sigma-algebras

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are usually random variables, not sets. So $A = \Omega\backslash X$ has no meanining

Comment: Added original exercise above. I know what you mean, but then $\sigma(X)$ would not make sense as well... So I thought X,Y are just measureable sets. Edit: Ah, okay, I saw your definition now. But we did not introduce this definition yet.

Comment: I've given you the definition of $\sigma(X)$ below. You should carefully read this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Independent_.CF.83-algebras

Answer (score 4):

Here are the definitions that I've used:

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ for any $A \in \mathcal F$ and $B \in \mathcal G$.

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent if the events $X^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ and $Y^{-1}((-\infty,b])$ are independent events for every $a$ and $b$.

The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B) \subset \Omega : B \text{ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$ }\}$ is called the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable, and it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which $X$ is a random variable.

To prove what you've asked amounts to taking $X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(X)$ and $Y^{-1}(B') \in \sigma(Y)$ and showing that these events are independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. But at first its important for me if my solution is correct or not. But of course I will look at this too

Comment: @Thingsgonnachange Your solution is neither correct nor incorrect, it is offtopic, since X and Y are random variables and not events (as already explained to you).

Comment: Alright, thanks. Another question: $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X^{-1}(A)\cap Y^{-1}(B))$? I am a bit confused about the notation on the left hand side.

Comment: Doesnt the statement easily follow? Our definition of independent random variables: X and Y are independent if $P(X\in A,Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$                                    If we take $X^{-1}(A)\in \sigma(X)$ and $Y^{-1}(B)\in \sigma(Y)$ arbitrary, then $P(X^{-1}(A)\cdot Y^{-1}(B))=P(X^{-1}(A))P(Y^{-1}(B))$, which follows by definition. But thats too trivial..isnt it?